# Антоним к слову "защищать"

Tags: антонимы

Меня вчера озадачили вопросом: а какой антоним к слову "защищать"? Я сказал "нападать", но это не совсем антоним. А кто что думает по этому поводу?

Comment: Как вариант - обижать.

Comment: Сколько значений у этого слова, столько и антонимов может набраться. А заумные объяснения, как у многих предыдущих товарищей, лучше оставить при себе: школьные учебники по рус. яз. и так перегружены красивой научностью, которая ничего, кроме отвращения у учеников к предмету, не вызывает. Учитесь объяснять просто и доходчиво.

Comment: Ну, этот форум не для учеников. По-крайней мере, не только. И некоторым людям интересны как раз "заумные рассуждения", а не банальности, вроде того, писать ли "не" отдельно и сколько "н" в прилагательном.

Comment: Вам никто не мешает объяснить просто и доходчиво. Я думаю, такое объяснение будет принято с благодарностью.

Comment: А я всё же полагаю, что в любой деятельности (и в нашем, естественно, случае) конкретная практическая польза гораздо ценнее заумных теоретических изысков. Красивую вычурность при  желании можно сделать из чего угодно. Но зачем???

Comment: Я против пустых и бессодержательных теоретических "размышлизмов", но полагаю, что уважаемый Александр в запальчивости начинает скатываться к отрицанию теоретических исследований вообще, а это уже чревато... Уважаемый Александр! То, что Вы умеете грамотно и логично строить предложения, рассуждать о значении теории - это свидетельство того, что в свое время Вы читали не только сборники упражнений и справочники типа "Учись писать правильно", а штудировали и сочинения по теории языка.

Comment: >А я всё же полагаю,   
@alexander? Вам никто не мешает полагать. Но лучше бы Вы не просто полагали, а реализовалм свое положение дав именно тот ответ, который бы уловлетворял Вашим же требованиям. А практичекую пользу оценят.

Comment: А в чем конкретная польза от знания антонима к "защищает"? Мне представляется, что само понимание "антонимичности" гораздо полезнее и интереснее.  

И вообще, "нет ничего практичнее хорошей теории"

Comment: Ну в принципе быват, когда ищешь слово - и не можешь найти... Не оперировать же каждый раз примитивами, от которых Marina-ja открещивается.  
Но смысл, конечно, в том, что это тренировка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекстуальные (***контекстные***) антонимы – слова, которые вступают в антонимические отношения только в определенном контексте. Они не являются языковыми антонимами, не осознаются как слова с противоположным значением вне этого контекста.
Пример: И ненавидим мы и любим мы случайно, / Ничем не жертвуя *ни злобе, ни любви*. / И царствует в душе какой-то *холод* тайный, / Когда *огонь* кипит в крови. (М.Ю. Лермонтов) 
Большинство слов языка не содержит признака, способного к противопоставлению, следовательно, антонимические отношения для них невозможны, однако в переносном значении они могут обрести антоним.

Comment: И?...........

Comment: Мой ответ был на "А мне кажется, это все-таки не совсем антонимы". Поскольку для точности ответа необходимо было различное выделение, мне пришлось писать в разделе "Ответ", а не в "Комментировать".

Comment: Вы можете смело использовать *различное* **выделение** в комментариях. 
Но я не об этом. Это антонимы или нет?

Comment: Да, это антонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Разные антонимы к разному значению слова "защищать". Антонимами будут или "нападать", или "обвинять"

Comment: Предавать, сдавать...

Comment: А мне кажется, это все-таки не совсем антонимы.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, мы более привыкли назвать их "частичными антонимами". тут не контекст важен, а именно - одно из значений.

Comment: Значение без (кон)текста невозможно — без любого контекста: словесного, бытового...
- Это хорек.
- Что такое хорек?
- Вот это хорек.

Comment: @Marina-ja, я бы сказала так: в основе любого смысла _был_ текст. Но после многократного повторения смысл сублимируется и остается в самом слове. Странно было бы изучать биологию методом "пальцеуказания" на хорьков и прочую живность. Нам же не приходится в каждом предложении объяснять, что значит каждое слово.

Comment: При изучении языка именно так и поступают )

Comment: >Значение без (кон)текста невозможно — без любого контекста: словесного, бытового... - Это хорек. - Что такое хорек? - Вот это хорек.

Вы удивительно хорощо знакомы с предметом "хорек".

Comment: Кино люблю смотреть )

Answer (score 1):

Универсального антонима (ну кроме примитива) не существует. 
В этой ситуации нападать - вполне пойдет. Пожалуй, самый универсальный. 
Еще - атаковать (более точно, но только в определенных контекстах), обвинять (в суде), нарушать (гуманитарное право) и т.д.

Comment: Антоним с не — это не примитив, норма )

Comment: Норма - не атоним примитиву.
Банальность - не аргумент, а банальность.

Comment: В художественной речи — возможно, а если текст в научном или деловом стиле, то тогда уместнее будет использовать (есть вообще возникает необходимость в антониме) именно с не.

Comment: Marina-ja, не знаю что там в художественной речи, но Ваши банальности я за аргумент не счел. Простите.
Примитивный - означает простейший.

Comment: Простите, где вы увидели "банальности"? Просто знание предмета разговора — не более или не менее. Вы уж выберите сами)

Comment: Простите, но фраза "Норма - не атоним примитиву" есть банальность ибо смысла в ней не больше чем в утверждении типа "Глагол - это не название народности в Гималаях". 
Что касается вашего "ответа", то я просто не вижу содержательной связи с вопросом. Поэтому он тоже банален (хотя я не это имел в виду под банальностью).   
ЗЫ Никто не опровергает ваше знание предмета. Только это не "предмет разговора". Еслия ошибаюсь и ваши знания действительно имеют отношение к разговору, я буду рад это понять.

Comment: Вы сами себя цитируете, сами с собой спорите... Где-то я уже с таким подходом встречалась.

Comment: >Вы сами себя цитируете, сами с собой спорите... Где-то я уже с таким подходом встречалась.  

Да, мне это всегда говорят, когда по теме сказать нечего. 
Особенно часто это приходится слыщать от знающих тему.
Здорорво, видать, вас "примитив" задел. 
Спасибо за содержавтельную дискуссиию. )

Comment: "Остапа несло". По-моему, @behemothus тоже... К сожалению. Вы _действительно_ процитировали себя и потом "сами себя высекли", как унтерофицерская вдова. Ужасно Вы любите спорить, все-таки!

Answer (score 0):

Нападать - не антоним. С точки зрения теории отношений это не противоположное, а обратное значение. Иногда они совпадают, но не всегда. Например, ниже-выше можно понимать как антонимы, а можно - и как обратные друг к другу отношения (если А ниже В, то В выше А).

В Вашем примере еще сложнее, так как отношение "защищать" трехместное: "А защищает В от С". Так вот, действие С в этом случае будет "нападать", а В - что-то вроде "быть защищаемым".

А вообще-то "антоним" к "защищает" - "не защищает".

**Дополнение**. После некоторых раздумий я поняла, почему меня не устраивает "нападать" как антоним к слову "защищать". Дело в том, что "нападать" связано с исходным словом двояко. Действительно, пусть А защищает В от С. При этом, видимо, С *нападает* на В (нападать-1). С другой стороны, А может перестать защищать В и даже полностью перемениться, нападать на В. Это - нападать-2. Именно его можно считать антонимом, а нападать-1 - нет.

Кстати, второе понимание возникает не во всех случаях "защиты". Например, "Стена защищает город", "Знание защищает от ошибок", "Бронежилет защищает от пуль". Во всех этих случаях "действующее лицо" никак не может нападать!

Comment: Н.П.Клесников (покойный профессор Ростовского университета)"Словарь антонимов": Защита - нападение,защита - обвинение,защитить - напасть, защитник - обвинитель

Comment: Извините, правильно "Колесников"

Comment: DocentI, в лингвистике нет четкого разделения понятий "обратное" и "противоплоное" (ну пока в формальную логику не ударились).

Да и сам тезис относительно того, что нападать - обратное, весьма спорен даже в теории отношений. Мы имеем дело не с отноешнием, а с действием по реализации отношения. Т.е. надо рассматривать все на множестве возможных *отношений* между А и Б.

Comment: Что "обратность" спорна - не отрицаю, хотя бы потому, что отношение трехместное. Но вообще понятие "антоним" для меня мало понятно. Мне нравится мнение, что антоним - это слабый синоним. Например: "красивый", "симпатичный", "обыкновенный", "непривлекательный", "уродливый". Тут ясно, что идет убывание признака вплоть до полностью противоположного состояния. В других же случаях непонятно, что именно противопоставляется. Пожалуй, я сформулирую это в виде отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Мне кажется, что противоположным действием к защите является, скорее, "неспособность защитить". Ну, типа "коротковата кольчужка". То есть пассивное состояние, а не обязательно активное.

Comment: DocentI, защищать переходный глагол. Если защищать есть дефтвие от А к Б, то антонимом должно служить противоположно действие дейстие от А к Б. Искать - прятать, помогать-вредить, занимать (в правильном значении)  - одалживать, одевать - раздевать... Какая "неспособность"? 
Хотя, конечно, любопытно, насколько можно па-разному понимать само понятие, простите за каламбур... "Препятсврвать защите" я бы еще призадумался, но тут уже тороичная операция получается.

Comment: Вот при чем тут переходность - не поняла, знаний не хватает. Я просто представила себе "защиту" не со стороны человека, а, скажем "стена защищает город". Что тогда будет антонимом? Нападение уж совсем не при чем.

Comment: переходность - чситайте, что это бинарность. Некоммутативная.