# Что такое "антоним"

Tags: терминология

Понятие *антоним* всем известно с начальной школы и кажется довольно простым.

> Антонимы, (от греч. «anti» — «против» и «onyma» — «имя») — это слова, принадлежащие к одной и той же части речи и имеющие противоположные значения.

Однако понять какие именно слова противоположны, не всегда легко, как показывает [обсуждение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Хотелось бы понять, что лингвисты понимают под этим термином? Легче всего понять противоположность прилагательных, ведь они указывают на наличие/отсутствие некоего качества (полный - пустой) или на присутствие его в разной мере (горячий - холодный). Четкое противопоставление есть и у наречий.

Сложнее с существительными. Как мне кажется, их противоположность основана на присутствии того же "качественного" смысла, как в прилагательных. Интересно обо всем этом сказано в [здесь](http://russkiyjazik.ru/73/)

Но вот антонимичность глаголов вызывает у меня большие сомнения. Мне даже трудно быстро привести примеры. Например *лежать* и  *бежать* - антонимы или нет? Или даже *выиграть* и *проиграть*, хотя здесь можно согласиться.

Но вот посмотрите: А повелевает В, тогда В подчиняется А. Вроде, антонимы. Но построим по той же схеме пару: А дружит с В, тогда и В дружит с А  Тут уже синонимы (даже вообще совпадающие понятия). Как же различать эти случаи?

В общем, сведЕние **антонимичности** к **противоположности**, по-моему, не решает проблему, так как это по сути просто перевод названия на русский язык.

**Дополнение**. Мое недоумение по поводу "противоположных" понятий имеет давнюю природу. Как-то давно случилось мне вести занятия по логике (не математической). Просмотрела я вузовские учебники. И наткнулась на такой "глоссарий":

> Типы несовместимости понятий: соподчинение, противоположность, противоречие.
>   **Соподчинение** - это отношение между объемами двух или нескольких понятий, исключающих друг другу, но принадлежащих некоторому, более общему родовому понятию.
>   В отношении **противоположности (контрарности)** находятся объемы таких понятий, которые являются видами одного и того же рода, и притом одно из них содержит какие-то признаки, а другое эти признаки не только отрицает, но и заменяет их другими, исключающими (т.е. противоположными) признаками.
>   В отношении **противоречия (контрадикторности)** находятся такие два понятия, которые являются видами одного и того же рода, и при этом одно понятие указывает на некоторые признаки, а другое эти признаки отрицает, исключает, не заменяя их никакими другими признаками.

К антонимам автор относит понятия 2-го и 3-го типа.

Моя математическая душа этих определений никак не могла переварить. Во-первых, эти определения описывают не просто объемы понятий (множества), а затрагивают их структуру. Чем, спрашивается, с точки зрения теории множеств отличаются "соподчинение" и "противоположность"? Второе - частный случай первого, причем выделяется не с точки зрения "объема" понятия, а по какому-то другому основанию. Причем "противоположность" понятий сводится к "противоположности" некоего признака, включенного в понятие. Для меня это круг в определении.

Кстати, в хорошей книге по логике Ю.В.Ивлева ничего подобного не написано, так что  "противоположность" для объемов понятий вообще не вводится. Несовместимые (по объему) понятия никак не подразделяются. Соподчинение приводится как отношение между тремя понятиями, а не двумя.

В то же время "противоречие" (контрадикторность), "контрарность" и "субконтрарность" рассматриваются как отношения по содержанию, а не по объему, и имеют четкие формальные определения.

И еще одно наблюдение: противоположность в философском смысле - она такая же как в лингвистическом? Например, "форма - содержание", "явление - сущность" и т.п. ? Т.е. будет ли "содержание" антонимом к "форме"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Да просто я вообще не понимаю, как
> могут существовать антонимы к
> глаголам.

Мне кажется, это Ваше непонимание коренится в том, что Вы пытаетесь взять антонимию (в частности, глагольную) как абстрактно-мыслимое (и тем самым единообразное и общезначимое) явление, так сказать, in vitro. А это неверно. Языковые явления несколько более текучи, чем явления логические, релевантность их зачастую переменна, поскольку контекстно-зависима. Если взять, к примеру, глагол **лежать**, то в рамках контекстного отношвения "лучше за рубль лежать, чем за два **бежать**" у этого глагола будет один антоним, в рамках отношения "кто стоймя **стоял**, тот лежмя лежит" - другой, в рамках отношения "да лежи ты, не **высовывайся**!.." - третий и т.д.

> К чему же брать противоположность?

- к основной семе лексического (не грамматического) значения, если речь о примерах вне контекста.

> противоположность в философском смысле
> - она такая же как в лингвистическом?
> Например, "форма - содержание", "явление -
> сущность" и т.п. ? Т.е. будет ли
> "содержание" антонимом к "форме"?

- Трактуют разнообразно. Если придерживаться классической гегелевой диалектики, приведённые Вами парные понятия взаимодополнительны (одно предполагает другое) и находятся в отношении соподчинения: содержание и форма суть аспекты явления, явление и сущность - аспекты вещи.

Answer (score 1):

О как... Целая тема. А в чем проблема я, честно говоря, не очень понимаю...

> > > А повелевает В, тогда В подчиняется А. Вроде, антонимы. Но построим по той же схеме пару: А дружит с В, тогда и В дружит с А

Вы неправильно трактуете "противоположный". Я постарался объяснить вам математизировано... Видимо, не получилось. Считайте пока, что "противоположный" у лингвистов синонимично "обратному". А то, что вы назвали - это скорее залог. В номинативных языках нет точного понятия, отображающего сие днйствие... А в эргативных, если не ошибаюсь, это называется эргативной меной.

> лежать и бежать - антонимы или нет?

Да, но слабенькие. В очень узком значении. Или - редких контекстах, с какой колокольни тоже пытались объяснить. На самом деле это правильнее назвать частичными антонимами. Но самом деле все антонимы (как и синонимы) - частичные, но в большинстве случаев об этом не вспоминают.

Кстати, вы хороший пример привели, чтобы возразить на ваше желание найти здесь математическую аналогию. Его только надо дополнить (ну или можно чуточку изменить): "лежать - стоять - двигаться". Перед нами триада, любая пара элементов которой является антонимами. Ситуация совершенно невозможная в математическом понимании слов обратный или противоположный.

Comment: Да просто я вообще не понимаю, как могут существовать антонимы к глаголам. За очень редким исключением. В чем "противоположность" двух действий? Например _заснуть_ - _проснуться_? Или _заснуть_ - _разбудить_? Или еще как-то?  
Я еще понимаю глаголы состояния, тогда может быть наличие/отсутствие. Но в других случаях?

Comment: Ну, собственно, "обратность" и "противоположность" в моих примерах - свойства отношений, а глаголы "лежать", "стоять" не описывают таковых.  
Просто получается, что в одном понятии "антоним" объединяется много разных "противоположностей". В частности, я никак не могу принять "нападать" как антоним к "защищать". То есть пока не задумаюсь - вроде так. Но вот как попытаюсь объяснить - ан нет, не выходит.

Comment: Отвлекитесь от бинарных отношений. Мне, кажется, они вас только путают. 
Попробуйте в категориях цели. Есть действие, следвием которого будет или может стать неккий результат. Антоним - действие, которое: а) отдалет этот результат б) препятвует достиженнию такого результата в) имеет следвием противоположный результат - все годится. В последнем случае "противоположный" - в любом смысле, кроме коммутативного - с ним не всегда проходит, не только по причине подобной отношению "быть другом".

Comment: Ну вот я и говорю, что понятие "противоположный" - множественное и очень разнообразное. И вообще, для чего оно нужно в случае глаголов? Из одного слова получается целый спектр слов, мало связанных друг с другом. Например, к "заснуть" - "мешать спать" (отдаляет результат), "разбудить" (препятствует достижению результата), "проснуться" (имеет следствием противоположный результат), бодрствовать (несколько менее точное значение, не учитывает "начало" действия), и даже "спать" - противоположность "началу действия".  
По-моему, все отношения очень интересные, но почему они антонимы?

Comment: Думаю, что глагол смутил меня множественностью своих внутренних смыслов: здесь и само действие, и действующее лицо (залог), и начинание/завершение/продолжительность, и много еще других оттенков. К чему же брать противоположность? 

Написала Дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: >И вообще, для чего оно нужно в случае глаголов?   

Для общности.