# Еще об антонимах

Tags: терминология

Этот вопрос - продолжение разговора об антонимах [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) и 
[здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11312/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC).
Для начала прошу помочь мне в выборе терминологии. Я в ней несколько "плаваю" и буду благодарна тем, кто наведет порядок в моих мыслях.  Я слышала о таком понятии, как "сема"

> Сема (от греч. sema - знак) - минимальная, предельная единица плана содержания. С. представляют собой элементарные отражения в языке различных сторон и свойств обозначаемых предметов и явлений действительности.

Так вот, относятся ли к семам "подсмыслы", отражаемые в грамматических формах? Например, залог?  Далее буду предполагать, что так и есть.

Вчера вела занятия по математике у филологов, как раз проходили отношения. Спросила их, что будет антонимом к слову "заснуть". Они сказали - "проснуться", а остальные варианты:  "разбудить", "бодрствовать" и т.п. - отвергли.

Слово "заснуть" включает семы *спать, начало действия, самостоятельно выполняемое действие*. Если отрицать все эти смыслы, получим *бодрствовать, установившееся действие, действие, направленное извне*.

Пронумеруем семы 1, 2, 3. Если отрицать только часть из них, получим такие варианты "противоположных" слов:

1. Не 1, 2, 3. Просыпаться
2. 1, не 2, 3. Спать.
3. 1, 2, не 3. Усыплять, укладывать спать (первое слово имеет оттенок "убивать")
4. Не 1, не 2, 3. Бодрствовать.
5. Не 1, 2, не 3. Разбудить.
6. 1, не 2, не 3. Что-то вроде "поддержать в сонном состоянии". Смысл теоретически возможный, но экзотический.
7. Не 1, не 2, не 3. Что-то вроде "не давать спать".

В принципе, можно выделить в "заснуть" и другие семы, и к каждой попробовать построить отрицание. Например, учесть разницу между "заснуть" и "засыпать" (совершенная-несовершенная форма). Честно говоря, не могу точно сказать, как отрицать эту сему. Например, чем будут отличаться варианты (не 1, не 2, не 3, 4) и (не 1, не 2, не 3, не 4)?

Так что же все-таки является антонимом в слову "заснуть"? И почему первое, что приходит в голову - именно "проснуться"? А другие варианты активно отвергаются сознанием?

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в том, что основную смысловую нагрузку несет сема №1. Остальные являются дополнительными, уточняющими. Именно поэтому в словаре антонимов даются такие пары:
  
1. спать - бодрствовать (т.е. процесс, выполняемый самостоятельно, но противоставление состояния)
2. засыпать - просыпаться ( переход А->Б и наоборот)
3. будить - усыплять

Comment: @gecube, согласна, я тоже пришла к такому мнению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виды глагола должны совпадать.

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Хотя я не видела, где это явно прописано. В определении говорится только, что это одна и та же часть речи. Впрочем, я не читала строго научных трудов на эту тему.